# how to copy mp4 file generated by FFMPEG spawn using another FFMPEG spawn

Tags: node.js, linux, ffmpeg

I am using the following code that records screen on Linux and the output is an mp4 file.

```
const transcodeStreamToOutput = spawn('ffmpeg',[
'-hide_banner',
'-loglevel', 'error',
// disable interaction via stdin
'-nostdin',
// screen image size
'-s', `${BROWSER_SCREEN_WIDTH}x${BROWSER_SCREEN_HEIGHT}`,
// video frame rate
'-r', `${VIDEO_FRAMERATE}`,
// hides the mouse cursor from the resulting video
'-draw_mouse', '0',
// grab the x11 display as video input
'-f', 'x11grab',
    '-i', `${DISPLAY}`,
// grab pulse as audio input
'-f', 'pulse',
    '-ac', '2',
    '-i', 'default',
// codec video with libx264
'-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-profile:v', 'main',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-x264opts', 'nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut',
    '-minrate', `${VIDEO_BITRATE}`,
    '-maxrate', `${VIDEO_BITRATE}`,
    '-g', `${VIDEO_GOP}`,
// apply a fixed delay to the audio stream in order to synchronize it with the video stream
'-filter_complex', 'adelay=delays=1000|1000',
// codec audio with aac
'-c:a', 'aac',
    '-b:a', `${AUDIO_BITRATE}`,
    '-ac', `${AUDIO_CHANNELS}`,
    '-ar', `${AUDIO_SAMPLERATE}`,
// adjust fragmentation to prevent seeking(resolve issue: muxer does not support non seekable output)
'-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
// set output format to mp4 and output file to stdout
'-f', 'mp4', '-'
]
```

);

I need to run `ffmpeg -i captured.mp4 -c copy new.mp4` using another spawn process on the output.
I tried the following :

```
const newStdOut =  spawn('ffmpeg',[

    '-i', `${transcodeStreamToOutput.stdout}`, 
    '-codec:v', 'copy', 
    '-codec:a', 'copy', 
    '-f', 'mp4', '-'
    ]
);
```

But it is not working. I would appreciate any help.